# How to read values from dictionary <String, List<Component>> on the basis of key passed using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a dictionary object as below:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Component>> dicCountries = new Dictionary<string, List<Component>>();
```

Now **dicCountries** is grouped on the basis of region ID, so I want to get all the `List<Component>` when I pass region ID.

Is it possible using Linq or do we need to use C# code to read it.

Please suggest!!

Comment: What do you mean by : `Now dicCountries is grouped on the basis of region ID`  ? do you have `regionID` as key in dictionary ?

Comment: @Habib, Yes Region ID is key and List<Component> are the collection of coutnries components, so like first key is "123" which represent "ASIA", so all the countries of asia will be there in List <Component>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = dicCountries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == regionID).Value;
```

or

```
var result = (from x in dicCountries
where x.Key == regionID
select x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Personally, I think the first one is cleaner. And by the way, Linq or no Linq.. it's all C#

**UPDATE:**

Actually, when using `FirstOrDefault`, it might return a `NULL` and therefore you should check the code first. So:

```
var result = dicCountries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == regionID);

List<Component> components = null;
if (result != null)
{
    components = result.Value;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I just remembered.. `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` cannot be compared with null and you would need to check like this instead:

```
if (!result.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, List<Component>>)))
```

which just goes to prove... sometimes LINQ is not the cleanest solution. In most cases it is, but not in this case.. so go with the easier solution:

```
List<Component>() list;
if (dicCountries.ContainsKey(regionID))
{
    list = dicCountries[regionID];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply as I am looking for List<Component> type of return, how can I read using above code as it returns KeyValuePair

Comment: Thank you it's really use for us